# Invalid number of vertices on an edge - Error while exporting

Tags: export

[image: The error I'm getting.]

I'm using the [DFF Importer/Exporter](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=21598). Using that I imported a player model from **GTA** and edited it *(changed UV map, deleted some vertices, added some vertices)*. Now I can't export it. I just get this error and it exports a file which is **0 bytes** in size.

Thanks for any help in advance. :)

Comment: Are you exporting with Tangent space?

Comment: @Fuboski I don't know what that is.